# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'loglevels'

Tags: python-3.x

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
{
    'name': "myfirstModel",
'summary': """
    Short (1 phrase/line) summary of the module's purpose, used as
    subtitle on modules listing or apps.openerp.com""",

'description': """
    Long description of module's purpose
""",

'author': "My Company",
'website': "http://www.yourcompany.com",

# Categories can be used to filter modules in modules listing
# Check https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/master/odoo/addons/base/module/module_data.xml
# for the full list
'category': 'Uncategorized',
'version': '0.1',

# any module necessary for this one to work correctly
'depends': ['base'],

# always loaded
'data': [
    # 'security/ir.model.access.csv',
    'views/views.xml',
    'views/templates.xml',
],
# only loaded in demonstration mode
'demo': [
    'demo/demo.xml',
],
}
```

i got this error while creating a new module in odoo... i am unable to import 'loglevels' in pycharm...?
any help is appreciated...